# jquery add, remove class

Tags: jquery, class, addition

i have a field like
 
Some times i want to add the class attribute 'datepicker '. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) methods:

```
$("#yourElementId").addClass("datepicker");
```